# Spring Kafka Multi Concurrency Consumer - Commit offset Failed

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring with Kafka to consume the data from Kafka topics. I have configured the concurrency as 10. So different threads poll the broker for the messages and processing the messages. Even after some time (processed successfully), we are receiving the same message back to a different thread to the consumer. we are able to process the received messages within configured max.poll.interval.ms=1500000.

Please find the below-configured properties of Kafka consumer. I have configured the auto-commit through Kafka.

```
    group.id=ips-request-group //group id
    enable.auto.commit=true // auto commit
    auto.commit.interval.ms=60000 // auto commit inverval
    session.timeout.ms=100000 // session time out
    request.timeout.ms=610000 // request time out
    fetch.max.wait.ms=500  //polling time out
    heartbeat.interval.ms=20000 // heart beat interval
    auto.offset.reset=latest  //consuming latest messages.
    key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer // key
    value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer //value
    max.poll.records=10 // max polling records
    max.poll.interval.ms=1500000 // max polling interval ms /*
```

Could you please help me to resolve duplicate receiving messages to Kafka consumer.

Comment: You need to provide much more information; how do you know you got duplicates? Did a rebalance occur for some other reason (e.g. another member joined). I recommend never using auto.commit - it's more reliable for the listener container to do the commits in a more predicable fashion (after every RECORD or BATCH).

Comment: Hi Gary, When any message came we are validating. is the particular transaction existed or not DB. If the transaction has already existed we are inserting to tracker table with some description.  Can't we commit the messages offset through auto interval?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is on the publishing side. Your consumer should store the partition and offset as well in the DB; I don't see how you can possibly get a duplicate if no rebalance occurred.

Comment: Even we are processing the messages with in the time also we are receiving the below message in the logs. WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Auto-commit of offsets ced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

Comment: Which means a rebalance **did** occur; you need to add de-duplication logic in your consumer to deal with such situations. You need to reduce `max.poll.records` or increase `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: Even we have processed the messages within the time interval why partitions are getting rebalanced?  When partitions are rebalanced we are receiving the same message through the different consumers. If you have an idea of this, could you please provide the information about why it's happening?  If we shouldn't use auto-commit offset interval what is the bestway to commit the message offset to kafka broker?

Comment: I can't say why the rebalance occurred. As I said; it's best to let the container perform the commits; it's more reliable. By default, it commits the offsets at the end of the batch (all records processed), use `AckMode.RECORD` to commit each offset after each record is processed; it will minimize the possibility of duplicates. In the upcoming 2.5 release, together with coopertative rebalancing, the chance of duplicates will be minimized further. But the key is to make sure you can process all the records within `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: Thanks, Gary, I will commit each message after successfully processed.

Answer (score 0):

To commit the offset after each record is proceessed; set `auto.commit.enabled=false` and set the container property `ackMode` to `AckMode.RECORD`.

Comment: Currently i set the ack mode to AckMode.MANUAL to commit the offset manually and concurrency is 10 or more. I am using BatchMessageListener. I am receiving a list of messages in the listener. Can you please help me how to commit the offset of each particular message after processing.  public void onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records) {
      records.forEach(action -> {
        this.messageListener.process(action.value());
      });
  }

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to use a batch listener and commit individual offsets; use a record listener instead. If you really want to do it, add `Consumer<?, ?>` as a parameter and manually commit each offset that way. The commits **must be performed on the listener thread**.